# synchronising navigation states

Tags: jquery, list

I have managed to synchronise two navigation levels to display on and off with jQuery. I want the user to move the mouse outside of both levels for the effect to work nicely. This seems to however only work for the first 'li' in my navigation. Any thoughts? Here is the fiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ScvpL/)

and my code:

```
//Maintain over state for main nav and sub nav
$('#mainNav li').mouseover(function(){  
    $(this).children("a").removeClass("whiteHighlight");
    if($('#mainNav li span').css('display') == "block"){ 
        $(this).children("a").addClass("whiteHighlight");
    }
}); 
//Remove over state for both when exiting sub nav
$('#mainNav li span').mouseout(function(){      
    if($('#mainNav li span').css('display') == "none"){ 
        $(this).prev().removeClass("whiteHighlight");
    }       
}); 
//Remove over state for both when exiting main nav
$('#mainNav li').mouseout(function(){       
    if($('#mainNav li span').css('display') == "none"){ 
        $(this).children("a").removeClass("whiteHighlight");
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to optimize your code, but in the interest of learning, here's the actual problem you're having. When you test:

```
if($('#mainNav li span').css('display') == "block"){
```

jQuery will look for ALL instances of `#mainNav li span`, but only test the first one. You want to test only the `span` inside of `this`:

```
if($('span',this).css('display') == "block"){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ScvpL/1/

Comment: Hi, thank you kindly for that explanation which does what I want to achieve. Please feel free to provide more information on how to optimize my code if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

On your mouseout, you are checking if($('#mainNav li span').css('display') == "none"), this span does not refer to the span inside the li the user has just moved away from, it refers to an array of all the spans that exist in the all the li in #mainNav.

You don't need JS for this anyway, i've fixed it for you without JS, just added this css:

```
#mainNav li:hover {background:#fff;}
#mainNav li:hover a {color:#333;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesking/ScvpL/2/

Comment: Thanks for your response James, however I need the hover state to work for the 'a' tag within the li and not on the upper level li itself. Apologies if that wasn't clear.